# Should integer types be cast explicitly (eg `int` to `unsigned`) or does this just add clutter?

Tags: c++, c

This is a pretty minor question, so my apologies if it is too broad or possibly a duplicate. I searched and found several questions regarding how implicit integer conversion works, but none asking whether it is a good thing. I wouldn't ordinarily have cared about this at all, but all the loud and irritating warnings that compilers give about implicit conversions made me wonder whether this is considered a problem.

As a simple example, here is a snippet calling a function that takes a linked list, an integer (index), and an unsigned integer (range) which removes the specified range from the linked list.

```
const int64_t first = foo;
const int64_t last  = bar;
const int     diff  = last - first; /* int for example's sake */
/* ... */
ll_delete_range_at(baz->ll, first+1, diff-1);
```

Dead simple; not terribly interesting. But clang complains that the values passed to the function are shortened and in the second case the sign is changed. Assuming that I know (as I do here) that there will not be an overflow problem, and that the values are always positive, is this actually a problem? Should one explicitly cast like this?

```
ll_delete_range_at(baz->ll, (int)(first+1), (unsigned)(diff-1));
```

As far as I understand it, this changes nothing other than to add clutter and explicitly state that the programmer is aware of the casts being done and is confident that they are OK. Is that worth the clutter?

Comment: How do you "know" that the values are always positive and in range?  If you really do know then consider using `int` (or `int32_t`) in the first place instead of int64_t.

Comment: I think it does provide information to someone reading the code. It tells that the cast is intentional and thought-out. Thus it's more than just clutter.

Comment: @user3738870 although one can never be sure if such casts are intentional and thought out; or if the coder just wanted to silence a warning and it might in fact be obscuring a bug.

Comment: What @M.M said. In my experience, at least 9 times out of 10 a cast was mindlessly inserted to shut up a warning, and usually it's wrong.

Comment: The original code uses int64_t only because it gets the value from a function that returns one. It wasn't for any particular reason. I know the values are correct in the actual code because I explicitly check. I just didn't include any of that in the example for brevity (I hate it when questions include lots of a person's code: nobody cares).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Clutter from frequent casting is a sign of bad architecture, not a sign that explicit casting is wrong.**

1. If you know that specific variables or members will always be in a specific range or size, then declare them with the appropriate type from the beginning.
2. If the types you have to work with need to be declared with a specific range or size, then that has a reason, and that reason will be valid wherever you use them, so stick to the types throughout your code.
3. If you have a special case where you must cast (e.g. when combining two libraries that use different types), then encapsulate that cast in a helper function or wrapper class with proper error handling.

Comment: In a case such as this, the values could well be negative or positive when declared. The purpose of the function they're in is mainly to sort out what to do with the various possible values (they could both be 0 which has a meaning, they could be -1 which has another meaning, or some other combination). By the time this function call is made I am certain the values are correct. Should a helper function be written to do the casting in that case? Or is my function too complicated in general?

Comment: Sounds to me you are abusing an integer to represent not just a value, but also the state of the value (or the object it belongs to). That smells of bad architecture. Not in the function, but in the design of the struct, class or whatever it is that gets passed to it.

Comment: It wasn't my design. I'm getting 3 values from another process (Neovim) representing changed lines: two integers and a list of strings. They wrote it such that the values must be interpreted to figure out what exactly is happening. An empty list of strings with a range means lines were deleted, an empty range with strings means lines were inserted... and so on. I wouldn't have done it this way, but I didn't write it. Also worth noting that it isn't documented, so I figured this out through trial and error.

Comment: Then that is the third case: You are working with a library and are forced to cast. I would probably create a class that takes the parameters of that library in its constructor, evaluates the data (and throws if necessary) and exposes clean getters for valid types as needed.

Comment: That would be the best idea if possible, however my particular code is C (I tagged C++ as well because I thought the question was equally applicable) so no classes for me. It would probably be wise to write a few small functions that operate on a struct and return enum values indicating the action taken to crudely emulate what a class might accomplish.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2):

C style casting to `int` snd `unsigned` should be avouded, because in my experience accidentally feeding them pointers and it becoming a reinterpret cast.  Use `static_cast`.

Second, those casts are a sign of errors waiting to happen; if `int` doesn't fit the `int64_t` we just got an unspecified overflow.  And a large unsigned value above `2^31` is probably not the number of elements we want to delete when `diff==0`.

So in that sense they are great documentation of where the code has dangerous problems.

The current programmer "knows" that the values are safe.  The different programmer 7 years, months or days from now "knows" that any valid 64 bit value can be used for `first` and `last`, and that a `diff` of `0` is reasonable and later code shouldn't choke.

Describing the contract of code where diff cannot be 0 and two 64 bit values must be within 2^31-1 of each other makes the code smell here more apparent.

All of which follows from an <s>innocuous</s> scary pair of C style casts and some numerically questionable function calls.

Explicit casts are better than implicit conversion, but the type conversion itself is fraught here.  Often type changes are a sign of bugs and fencepost errors to come.  Program defensively and deal with the bounds checks unless you know the code is in a critical performance path; then, get the types right in the critical performance path.

Comment: Two spellings to fix (1) `"bdcoming"` and (2) `"cose"` (I'll leave them to you rather than taking liberty with your answer)

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have tagged this C++. I thought it and C would be equally applicable here. My code is actually C, so the casts have to be "C style". Mainly I agree with you, although a diff of 0 is actually explicitly handled both here and in `ll_delete_range` and includes a comment as well. I have nonetheless decided that types should be a bit clearer earlier on. There is no choice but to cast somewhere, since the integers are received as `uint64_t` via IPC, but making those casts immediately is a much smarter solution.

Comment: @rofl comments are great descriptions of what code used to do (before someone changed it and forgot to update the comment) and why the system crashed.  Comments rarely prevent the crash.  And yes, C++ and C are quite different languages.